# Getting error on System.IO.Compression when trying to use ZipFile class

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I am using ZipFile class.

A reference/dll must be added in order to use this class. It seems that you can use both the `System.IO.Compression` and the `Ionic.Zip` dll (one at a time ofcourse).

In my case, only the latter works. The problem though, is that the `Ionic.Zip` doesn't seem to have the method: `ExtracToFile(...)` which overwrites an existing file. I need this method badly.
Instead, I can only do:

`zip.Extract(extractDirectory);` (Then I get an error saying the file already exist)

If I do:

```
zip.ExtractToFile(extractDirectory);
```

I get an error saying that the method ExtractToFile does not exist.

Another thing to note, is that doing `Using System.IO.Compression`, I get an error when I do:

```
var zip = ZipFile.Read(finalFileToUnzip)
```

which says that it can't find ZipFile (although I did add the dll as a reference, doing "Add Reference -> and selecting the .dll file")

If I do `Using Ionic.Zip`, it will accept: `var zip = ZipFile.Read(finalFileToUnzip)`

I am not able to find any info or previous posts about this issue, I hope anyone can help

Any idea about what might be the problem?

Here is more code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listWithZipToUnpack.Count; ++i)
{
    extractDirectory = Path.Combine(projectPath.ToString(), pathDir + listWithZipToUnpack[i]);

    var finalFileToUnzip = Path.Combine(projectPath.ToString(), pathDir, "Lely", listWithZipToUnpack[i]);

    if (finalFileToUnzip.Equals("--Vælg fil--")) { continue; }

    using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(finalFileToUnzip))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(extractDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(extractDirectory+"-"+listWithZipToUnpack[i]);
        }

        foreach (var zipArchiveEntry in zip.Entries)
        {
            zipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile(extractDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using .NET framework 4.5.2

Comment: `ZipFile` was added in .NET 4.5... which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: sounds like you have a `Path` Issue here can you show how you are assigning the file / file path of the contents that you need to have zipped..

Comment: I am using version 4.5.2 of .NET.
I edited the code as added more code 2 it

Comment: What specific problem are you asking about? A compile error? An error on execution? Can you tell us *exactly* what error you're getting, and where?

Comment: I cannot use the method: ExtractToFile. It says that it doesn't exist. That is my problem

Comment: Without a complete code example it's impossible to say what's wrong. The code you posted _should_ compile fine, so if it's not then it's because of some detail you omitted from your question. That said, I will point out that even if you got this to compile, it still wouldn't work, because you are passing the directory name as the file name in the call to `ExtractToFile()`. For each archive entry, you need to combine the directory name with the entry name to get the file name to use to save the file.

Comment: What says that what doesn't exist? Does the compiler say that the method `ExtractToFile` does't exist, or do you get an error at runtime saying that the path you specified (the `extractDirectory`) doesn't exist?

Comment: The error is on compile time. It is VS12 that says the method doesn't exist

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it. The problem is that it is not enough to only add `System.IO.Compression` to references, you must also add `System.IO.Compression.Filesystem`

Comment: So you have to add it as a reference.

Comment: Yes, to the references. Not needed in the using statement.